# No signal on my desktop's HDMI output with a specific 4k TV

Tags: hdmi

Edit:
Starting in `nosetmode` image is now displayed but becomes all laggy when playing video. Investigation continues.

I've been struggling for a few days with my Gigabyte Desktop computer.

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04. My usual HDMI monitors are an old full HD TV or a desktop full HD monitor and everything worked fine.
I've rencently upgraded my TV for a 4K Sony Bravia and it's now impossible to get anything else than a blank screen and a "no signal" notification on TV.

The cable I'm using works fine on other Full HD / 4K devices.

The command `Xrandr` gives me the following output:

`Can't open display`

The command `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr -q` outputs the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1085mm x 610mm
   3840x2160     30.00*+  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   4096x2160     24.00    23.98
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1680x1050     59.88
   1600x900      60.00
   1280x1024     60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    30.00    59.94    29.97    24.00    23.98
   1024x768      60.00
   800x600       60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       60.00    59.94
```

DP-2 appears as disconnected when I unplug the HDMI cable. It seems the TV and my computer are communicating but nothing is displayed.

Needless to say I've been trying several HDMI cables, all of my TV settings and all the HDMI inputs, for the exact same result. The HDMI output was OK on that TV with the same computer running recalbox, so I would definetely exclude the hardware.

I'm really running out of ideas, if anyone has a lead, I would be really gratefull :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue and tried every solution I could find, in the end it turns out that I just had to reduce the refresh rate from 60 to 59.94.
[image]